# Regex positive look behind and look ahead

Tags: python, regex

I have some arbitrary output like such:

```
ABC1    1.1.1.1    20151118    active
ABC2    2.2.2.2    20151118    inactive
xxx     x.x.x.x    xxxxxxxx    active
```

I am trying to determine a pattern using regex to extract the second column values for lines that contain `ABC` and `active`

This is what I have come out with thus far, but I have gotten stuck...

My issue seems to be the whitespaces in between the first column and second column, however Python does not allow variable width patterns in look behinds.

```
(?<ABC)(\s+)(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)(?=\S+\s+active)
```

Comment: Maybe, you are looking for [`r'ABC\d*(\s+)(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(?=\s+\S+\s+active)'`](https://regex101.com/r/oZ8cJ6/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use lookbehind. You can use this regex and grab the captured group #1:

```
^ABC\S+\s+(\S+)(?=.*\sactive\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rD7fQ2/1)

**Code:**

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^ABC\S+\s+(\S+)(?=.*\sactive\b)', re.MULTILINE)

re.findall(p, input)
```

Comment: I can't seem to get results when using `search` or iterating through the results of `finditer`.